# Reformat code of TinyMCE in Silverstripe

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, silverstripe, reformatting

When i'm putting some HTML/avascript code in TinyMCE, the code reformats or disappears after saving the page. I want to disable this. 
Is there any way to stop the reformatting?

Comment: what do you mean by putting html/avascript in tinymce?

Answer (score 1):

There is a tinymce init parameter called cleanup. You need to set

```
cleanup: false,
```